# How Can I Echo This PHP 'Field Required' Message On My HTML Page?

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer, contact-form

I'm building a PHP form. This script cycles through the form's fields and tells me if they're empty or not. When I submit the form, it redirects me from index.html to contact.php and displays a blank page. I would like to display $errmsg above the form in index.html. What am I doing wrong? Here's where I'm pulling information from: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_required.asp

PHP:

```
<?php
$fields = array('name', 'email', 'telephone');
$error = false;
foreach($fields AS $fieldname) {
        if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname])) {
                $errmsg = 'Please Fill All Fields. '.$fieldname.' is empty!<br />';
                $error = true;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="contact.php">
    <div class="form-group">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $errmsg;?></span>
```

Here is my entire contact.php in case the issue is further down.

```
<?php
$fields = array('name', 'email', 'telephone');
$error = false;
foreach($fields AS $fieldname) {
        if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname])) {
                $errmsg = 'Please Fill All Fields. '.$fieldname.' is empty!<br />';
                $error = true;
        }
}

if(!$error) {
        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
                $message = $_POST['message'];
                $headers = "From: contact@example.com\r\n";
                $to = 'me@example.com';
                $subject = 'New Lead';
                $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $telephone\n Message: $message";
        mail('me@example.com', $subject, $body, $headers);
        header("Location: http://www.example.com/messagesent.html");
        die();
        }
}
?>
```

edit: Entire HTML Form. It's nested in Bootstrap sorry for spaghetti

```
<!-- Contact Form -->
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="contact.php">
        <div class="form-group">
                <span class="error">* <?php echo $errmsg;?></span>
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
                </div>
        </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="telephone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="250-555-555">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"></textarea>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</form>
<!-- End Contact Form -->
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire HTML of the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**Use Ajax Method**    

**index.html** 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>using Ajax in jQuery</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        label{
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").submit(function(event){
            // Stop form from submitting normally
            event.preventDefault();

            /* Serialize the submitted form control values to be sent to the web server with the request */
            var formValues = $(this).serialize();

            // Send the form data using post
            $.post("contact.php", formValues, function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                $("#result").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></label> 
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
    </html>             



contact.php 


<?php
$fields = array('name');
$error = false;
foreach($fields AS $fieldname) {
        if(!isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name'])) {
                $errmsg = 'Please Fill All Fields. '.$fieldname.' is empty!<br />';
                $error = true;
        }
}

if($error==true){
    echo $errmsg;
    die();
}
else{
        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                $name = $_POST['name']; 
                $headers = "From: contact@example.com\r\n";
                $to = 'me@example.com';
                $subject = 'New Lead';
                $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $telephone\n Message: $message";
        mail('me@example.com', $subject, $body, $headers);
        header("Location: http://www.example.com/messagesent.html");
        die();
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run PHP code in a html-file unless you really go through some serious hoops to do it. Try renaming index.html to index.php instead.

Comment: Just tried and it still redirects to a blank contact.php

Comment: Is there a way to echo a message to an HTML page without running PHP in the page?

Comment: Great, that's step one. I'm writing a another longer answer as to why this is happening. Have patience ;)

Comment: Thanks! I look forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
            $fields = array('name', 'email', 'telephone');
            $error = false;
            foreach($fields AS $fieldname) {
                    if(!isset($_POST['fieldname']) || empty($_POST['fieldname'])) {
                            $errmsg = 'Please Fill All Fields. '.$fieldname.' is empty!<br />';
                            $error = true;
                    }
            }

            if(!$error) {
                    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                            $name = $_POST['name'];
                            $email = $_POST['email'];
                            $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
                            $message = $_POST['message'];
                            $headers = "From: contact@example.com\r\n";
                            $to = 'me@example.com';
                            $subject = 'New Lead';
                            $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $telephone\n Message: $message";
                    mail('me@example.com', $subject, $body, $headers);
                    header("Location: http://www.example.com/messagesent.html");
                    die();
                    }
            }
            ?>

    **Main Error:** 

    if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname])) {
            // your code
}
                    above line should be 

    if(!isset($_POST['fieldname']) || empty($_POST['fieldname'])) {
}
```

Comment: I had that piece of code printing the error message to contact.php originally and it worked fine, I just need it to echo to the html file instead of contact.php

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem here is that the action-attribute is sending you to contact.php, which actually isn't outputting any html code (hence the blank page). Your contact.php file is actually just a helper file for doing functions in the form, so sending the users to that file is pointless. They should, of course, be staying on the index.php file.

So first, change the "action" attribute in the form tag to point to index.php instead of contact.php.

Second, you need to require your contact.php file, so that your php-functions are actually accessible to the index.php file.

Third, because we are directing the submit to the same page, you need to check i the form has been submitted or not before loading the form.

So you're code should be looking kind of like this:

```
<?php

require 'contact.php'; // Path to your contact.php script

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Contact form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Contact Form -->
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
                <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { // I'm putting my if statement to check if form is submitted here, but you could put it anywhere you like as long as it's wrapping the error message in some way.?> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="error">* <?php echo $errmsg;?></span>
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
                        </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="telephone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="250-555-555">
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"></textarea>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        </form>
        <!-- End Contact Form -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is just quickly coded, just so you understand what is happening and why. You should adjust you're code according to your needs. Hope it helps.

Comment: In all my googling I never came across the require function. This is only my second day with PHP though. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped. Doing forms like this is kind of clunky though. For better usability you probably need to involve some kind of Javascript solution, but if you're just learning PHP, this is a good lesson.